# Internet Explorer 9 don't load the js and css but it works in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, http-status-code-404

Im doing this webpage http://www.xarcuterialamuntanya.com/
it works perfectly in FF and chrome but in IE fails. If you press F12 in IE and go network tab (reload then the webpage) you can see that CSS and JavaScript files are not loaded correctly. It apears 404 error.
Can anybody tell me whats wrong please???
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `<link href="/themes/prestashop/css/modules/blocklanguages/blocklanguages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >`

Change this to 

`<link href="themes/prestashop/css/modules/blocklanguages/blocklanguages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >`

That is remove the opening slash `/`

Comment: Your also getting a error on IE 10 = 'Object doesn't support property or method 'tinyscrollbar' es, line 47 character 4'

Comment: I change the path (also, i try to put absolute path like for http://www.xarcuterialamuntanya.com/themes/prestashop/css/global.css, you can see on the HTML tab) and still don't work.

Comment: The console error is couse IE are not loading the JS files also.
Does anybody can help me??